This is a safe strategy for aligned states in React?
I'm building a hook for data ordering, and it can receive state and setState from outside, defined by the user, but if they are not passed, I use an internal useState declaration.
But is this approach recommended? As follows:
export function useMaterialTableSort(data, columns, orderState, setOrderState) {

    if (orderState && setOrderState) {
        var columnOrder = orderState
        var setColumnOrder = setOrderState
    }
    else if (!orderState && !setOrderState) {
        var [columnOrder, setColumnOrder] = useState({})
    }
    else {
        throw Error("orderState and setOrderState must be defined!")
    }

    // rest of the component that uses columnOrder and setColumnOrder state
}

The other alternative would be to use an aligned state to update according to the outside state, but this would cause two renders
export function useMaterialTableSort(data, columns, orderState, setOrderState) {
    const [columnOrder, setColumnOrder] = useState(orderState || {})

    useEffect(() => {
        if (typeof orderState === "object") {
            setColumnOrder(orderState)
        }
    }, [orderState])

    // In the rest of the component, instead of using setColumnOrder, 
    //  which would cause a rendering loop, I would use setOrderState, 
    //   which is an outside state
}


It seems risky since you can't guarantee that the user of the hook will always pass or not pass the state/setState, meaning there's a chance you could inconsistently call the insternal useState and crash.

Does this code compile/run? AFAIK you shouldn't be conditionally calling hooks, so declaring a useState in a else-branch doesn't seem right to me. It might work due to variable hoisting, but I still recommend against it.

Also there's really no good usecase for var anymore, use const or let

@nbokmans it will compile and work fine as long as the hook is consistently called or consistently not called, but as soon as that changes it will break

since it is for internal use, I believe there would be a guarantee that the state and setState from outside were passed correctly.

if orderState is a state you do not need a useEffect to monitor it, you can write your condition directly cf=> https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect#updating-state-based-on-props-or-state

The first example is just flat out wrong, it breaks the Rules of Hooks. FWIW the second is also a bit incorrect as it's also considered a general React anti-pattern to store passed state/props/etc into local state. The general rule is don't store derived "state" in state, just reference it directly, or compute and memoize a derived value with the useMemo hook. Just about 100% of the time if you create a useState/useEffect coupling you should instead use the useMemo hook.

Calling useState conditionally breaks the rules of React hooks - it may work in practice, because a the caller of your function will likely consistently either supply or not supply orderState / setOrderState, but I would not recommend it.
You can re-write your hook like this:
export function useMaterialTableSort(data, columns, orderState, setOrderState) {

    const [internalOrderState, setInternalOrderState] = useState({});

    const [columnOrder,  setColumnOrder] = orderState && setOrderState 
        ? [orderState, setOrderState]
        : [internalOrderState, setInternalOrderState];

    // rest of the component that uses columnOrder and setColumnOrder state
}



since at the end of the day you want to order data you can just order it internally and return setColumnOrder to allow the user to also do moification outside the hook without needing to redeclare a use State
export function useMaterialTableSort(data, columns, orderState, setOrderState) {

const [internalOrderState, setInternalOrderState] = useState({});

const [columnOrder,  setColumnOrder] = useState({})
// rest of the component that uses columnOrder and setColumnOrder state

    return {
            orderedData://the data after ordering,
            setColumnOrder
           }

}
